# Support SVG on mobile platforms

Tags: javascript, svg, mobile-phones, mobile-website, raphael

Which mobile platform browser fully supports SVG? Interested JS + Raphaël + touchscreen

Answer (score 4):

I've tested raphael with Opera Mobile on Android and it works fine. Unfortunately it doesn't work with the default Android browser.

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw out there that [Mobile Safari](http://www.mattryall.net/blog/2008/09/iphone-21-adds-svg-support-to-mobile-safari) and [Opera Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mobile) have support.  Also, there are a few questions on this scattered about, for example: [Mobile Safari SVG rendering issues with raphaeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549228/mobile-safari-svg-rendering-issues-with-raphaeljs)

I would keep a watch out on wikipedia for this, it's the most updated information source I know of on SVG support: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics